# make one of listview item different style based on selected value android

Tags: android, listview

How can we set like different background color, font color for only 1 item in listview based on selected (clicked) item?

I want to make active button style upon clicking listview item, can we do that?

I am able to get the value of the clicked item, then how can we set that listview item to behave different than other item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the steps below:

1) First, **Create** a xml for single row of `ListView` (`single_row.xml`).

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/llList"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

2) **Create** a *Custom Adapter* for `ListView`:

```
 public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{   
 String [] text;
 Context context;
 int selectedPosition;
 private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

 public CustomListAdapter(Context context, String[] text, int selectedPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
        this.text = text;
        this.selectedPosition = selectedPosition;

        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                 getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView tv;
        LinearLayout llList;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Holder holder=new Holder();
        View rowView;       
             rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, null);
             holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
             holder.llList=(LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.llList);                    
         holder.tv.setText(text[position]); 

         holder.llList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                   holder.llList.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
            }
         });       

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

3) **Set** This *Custom Adapter* to your `ListView` in `onCreate()`:

```
int selectedItem = 0;     //Declare this Globally

lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
lv.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, yourStringList , selectedItem));
```

4) Then **get** the selected position of the `ListView` through `onItemSelectedListener:` and pass it to the adapter.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new View.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int position, long id) {
                selectedItem = position;
                CustomListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: for the 4th point, i put my onclick inside getView, how can i set selectedItem and adapter then?

Comment: Check the modification of 2nd snippet inside `getView()`

Comment: Work like a charms! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- define your own `CheckableLinearLayout` implement `Checkable` and override `abstract` method.
- let `CheckableLinearLayout` be root layout for your item view. and then,make a selector for root view to add selected effects.
- `ListView` chooseMode --> `singleMode`

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track the position of the current selected element like below:

```
    OnItemClickListener listViewOnItemClick = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int position, long id) {
                mSelectedItem = position;
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
```

And override the getView method of your adapter:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_list, null);

        if (position == mSelectedItem) {
            // set your color
        }

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: where i can get mAdapter variable? im using onclick method at getView so im not declaring adapter there